# Pandas: Sort the column on frequency by another column having same value grouped

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, frequency

I've dataframe which is group by **y column** and sorted on their **count column** of **y column**.

**Code:**

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(['y'])['y'].transform(pd.Series.value_counts)
df = df.sort('count', ascending=False)
```

**Output:**

```
x   y   count
1   a   4
3   a   4
2   a   4
1   a   4
2   c   3
1   c   3
2   c   3
2   b   2
1   b   2
```

Now, I want to sort **x column** on its frequency having same values grouped on **y column** like below:

**Expected Output:**

```
x   y   count
1   a   4
1   a   4
2   a   4
3   a   4
2   c   3
2   c   3
1   c   3
2   b   2
1   b   2
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt at sorting on column x ?

Comment: @Satyadev: I tried but didn't help as I'm newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need `groupby` and [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) and then [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) for expand index values by their counts to `DataFrame`:

```
s = df.groupby('y', sort=False)['x'].value_counts()
#alternative
#s = df.groupby('y', sort=False)['x'].apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
print (s)
y  x
a  1    2
   2    1
   3    1
c  2    2
   1    1
b  1    1
   2    1
Name: x, dtype: int64

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(s.index.values, s.values).tolist(), columns=['y','x'])
#change order of columns
df1 = df1.reindex_axis(['x','y'], axis=1)
print (df1)
   x  y
0  1  a
1  1  a
2  2  a
3  3  a
4  2  c
5  2  c
6  1  c
7  1  b
8  2  b
```

Comment: @jezrel: Sorry, I did a mistake. So, I edited my question. "count" column doesn't loss the ability of sorting. It should be sorted always.

Comment: Ok, but first column is OK? In first group `a` is sorted, in `c` and `b` is not.

Comment: Actually, **c** and **b** are sorted on frequency. As you can see that **c** column has two **2** and one **1** while **b** has only one **2** and one **1**.

Comment: Now it is OK, if same `length` like in group by `b` it can be swapped order.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an older version where df.sort_values is not supported. you can use:

```
df.sort(columns=['count','x'], ascending=[False,True])
```

Comment: Sorry, I did a mistake. So, I edited my question. "count" column doesn't loss the ability of sorting. It should be sorted always.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem. So what's not working now?

Comment: **x** column should be sorted without affecting **y** and **count** columns sorting. Sort **x** column without shuffling the values **y** and **count** columns

Comment: Will this work? df.sort(columns=['y','count','x'],ascending=[True,False,True])

Comment: **df.sort()** helps but not that much. I'd done in different way but let me check @jezrael answer too. May he has done something great.